# Differentiability of the function $x \mapsto |x|^{3/2}$ at $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Could someone please explain whether the function $$\vert x \vert^{3/2}$$ is differentiable at zero?  ($x$ here is a real number.)

I tried investigating the right and left-sided limits (i.e., the limits as $x$ approaches 0 from the right and left), and ended up with the expressions $$\frac{d^{3/2}}{d} \textrm{ and } \frac{(-d)^{3/2}}{d},$$ which do not appear to be equivalent... is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of the function $f(x) := |x|^{3 / 2}$ at $x = 0$ is given by the limit
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|h|^{3 / 2}}{h},$$
provided it exists.
To dispense with the absolute value symbol, we can evaluate the left- and right-hand limits separately. In the right-hand limit, that is, as $h \to 0^+$, we're considering values with $h > 0$, so
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{|h|^{3 / 2}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{h^{3 / 2}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} h^{1 / 2} = 0.$$ The left-hand limit (for which we're considering $h < 0$) is only slightly trickier:
$$\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{|h|^{3 / 2}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{(-h)^{3 / 2}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-}- \frac{(-h)^{3 / 2}}{(-h)} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} - (-h)^{1 / 2} = 0.$$
The left- and right-hand limits both have value $0$, hence so does the two-sided limit, i.e., the derivative itself:
$$f'(0) = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response!  It was very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.